# Disable the log from specific class/jar via logback.xml

Tags: java, hibernate, logging, logback, slf4j

In my application I use Java, Hibernate.

Logging : I use logback.xml

Can anyone suggest if there is a way to disable the logs from the below specific class from Hibernate jar.

**LOGGER to be removed from the specific class** : ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper

logback.xml:

```
<configuration>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <Pattern>
                %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
            </Pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <logger name="org.springframework" level="error"
        additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </logger>

    <root level="error">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Can you post your logback.xml configuration ?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Add the following to your `logback.xml` configuration file:

```
<logger name="org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper" level="OFF"/>
```

The instruction: `level="OFF"` tells Logback to disable all log output for a given logger.

Answer (score 6):

In your logback.xml configuration adding the following element should work

`<logger name="org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper" level="OFF"/>`