# How do I change the logging level for Gilead?

Tags: java, gilead

I'm getting a lot of records written to the log like this:

Jan 08, 2020 1:27:48 PM net.sf.gilead.core.PersistentBeanManager clonePojo 
INFO: Third party instance, not cloned

I'd like to stop them.  I'm assuming that if I were to change the logging level that this is using to something like WARN, they'd stop, but I can't seem to find how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think changing the log level to Warn will help as, this way you are trying to change the config level of your entire application.

Depending on the logging framework you use, it should help you configure this, to avoid printing logs of certain class/package.

See below answer to disable logs if you are using logback.
There should be similar options for other logging frameworks.It would be helpful, If you could specify the exact logging framework you are using.

[Disable the log from specific class/jar via logback.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47397442/disable-the-log-from-specific-class-jar-via-logback-xml)

Comment: We're using log4j version 1.2.16.  I've learned a couple of things since I posted. Apparently the creator of this project added in their own version of the gilead PersistenBeanManager.java class.  This is the source of the logged messages. I tried adding a logger to the log4j.xml file for the package within which that class exists, and set it to WARN.  It had no effect. I can't seem to affect the logging level of the gilead classes via log4j directly. I've seen numerous times on the Gilead help site where a user is directed to set logging to DEBUG, but it never says how to do it.