# Ignore logging messages from dependencies

Tags: java, mongodb, scala, log4j, logback

I'm attempting to configure a project that log's my info messages. This work's as expected but there are many other messages being logged at info level from a MongoDB dependency such as :

> 12:28:46 [main] INFO  org.mongodb.driver.cluster - No server chosen by
> com.mongodb.internal.async.client.ClientSessionHelper$1@2baa8d82 from
> cluster description ClusterDescription{type=REPLICA_SET,
> connectionMode=MULTIPLE,
> serverDescriptions=[ServerDescription{address=cluster-shard-00-00.zyqyw.mongodb.net:27017,
> type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING},
> ServerDescription{address=cluster-shard-00-02.zyqyw.mongodb.net:27017,
> type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING},
> ServerDescription{address=shard-00-01.zyqyw.mongodb.net:27017,
> type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}]}. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing
> out

I've configured logback.xml as :

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Is there a configuration I can use to just log messages from my own classes and/or packages and ignore thrid party logging messages such as `MongoDB` in this case?

Comment: Have you read through this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47401645/5761558 ?

Comment: Or, for that matter, the Logback documentation? And why are you tagging with `log4j` if you're using logback?

Comment: @ernest_k yes, thanks, I've voted to close as duplicate.