# Continuous Logs print in GridGain Spring boot Client node

Tags: spring-boot, ignite, gridgain

I have gridgain server running in Google cloud Kubernetes engine and there are spring boot client nodes to access data in gridgain. Spring boot client print following log continuously. How I disable this.

```
2021-06-01 05:29:28 INFO  [grid-timeout-worker-#22] o.a.i.i.p.q.s.IgniteStatisticsDummyStoreImpl.info():284 - Unable to save statistics obsolescence info on non server node.
2021-06-01 05:30:28 INFO  [grid-timeout-worker-#22] o.a.i.i.p.q.s.IgniteStatisticsDummyStoreImpl.info():284 - Unable to save statistics obsolescence info on non server node.
2021-06-01 05:31:28 INFO  [grid-timeout-worker-#22] o.a.i.i.p.q.s.IgniteStatisticsDummyStoreImpl.info():284 - Unable to save statistics obsolescence info on non server node.
```

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with this message. It doesn't indicate that something is wrong. It's related to SQL engine statistics. It's being printed only on client and daemon nodes. Anyway you can disable it on a logging level. Here is the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47397442/disable-the-log-from-specific-class-jar-via-logback-xml) describing how achieve that with Logback for example. In this case it would be something like that:

```xml
<logger name="org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.stat.IgniteStatisticsDummyStoreImpl" level="OFF"/>
```