# How to disable slf4j log in java

Tags: java, ffmpeg

Sorry for my poor English.

I'm using ffmpeg-cli-wrapper library in java

[main] INFO net.bramp.ffmpeg.RunProcessFunction - .\ffprobe.exe -version

[main] INFO net.bramp.ffmpeg.RunProcessFunction - .\ffprobe.exe -v quiet -print_format json -show_error -show_format -show_streams -show_chapters

How to remove this log?

try this:

1. java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("net.bramp.ffmpeg").setLevel(Level.OFF);
2. /logger name="net.bramp.ffmpeg" level="OFF"/ in logback.xml

but not work...

RunProcessFunction src:
https://github.com/bramp/ffmpeg-cli-wrapper/blob/master/src/main/java/net/bramp/ffmpeg/RunProcessFunction.java

Comment: So what logger are you *actually* using behind the slf4j facade?  `java.util.logging`?  Logback?  Something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the library's pom.xml, I see that ffmpeg-cli-wrapper usese logback 1.2.11. I would try to add a logback.xml basic configuration file to your project, and configure disabling the logger for that lib/class there. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47397442/disable-the-log-from-specific-class-jar-via-logback-xml), which has an example of a logback.xml config file, with answer that disables log for a specific class of exception.