How to disable loggers of a class or of whole package in kotlin?
I use mu.KLogging for logging in my application. I want to turn off logs of some class.
As I know for log4j it is possible with using
log4j.logger.foo = OFF,
but Kotlin-logging is a slf4j wrapper. Maybe there is some way for mu.KLogging too?

For example I have a lot of logs like
The [userInfo] property of the [com.life.chat.adapter.out.jpa.model.ParticipantEntity] entity was modified, but it won't be updated because the property is immutable.

of org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister class.
It's not a problem at all and such logs just make mess. That's why I would like to disable such logs.

You should be able to use the Logback configuration; see, for example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47397442/disable-the-log-from-specific-class-jar-via-logback-xml

It helped:
logging:
  level:
    org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister: OFF

But I decided to be careful and do not turn off this log and solve it problem
